# jquery - troubleshooting this jquery code

Tags: jquery

I am writing this routine where users can click on 3 buttons and the help divs will appear.

If the users click on any of the 3 buttons, the help divs will toggle and appear accordingly.  This appears to be done correctly with the code.

If the users click on the "close" button inside the help div, the help div will disappear.  This seems to be done correctly too.

If the users click outside of the help window (but not on the buttons), the window will also close.  This seems to be OK too.

But I am getting into a roadblock where I want the help window to stay open if the users click anywhere inside the help window except the close button.

My code is on jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/nzMAw/2/, I commented out the jquery line (near the end) that is giving me the problem.  It does not seem to get executed correctly when the script is run for the first time.  That is if I press any button for the first time, the help window will popup, but it will close if I click inside the window.  But after that, when I press the button again to open up the help window, the problematic code prevents the 'close' from closing the window.

I really appreciate any insight here.

TIA

```
$(function(){

$(document).click(function(event){

    var id = event.target.id;
    //var id=$(this).attr('id');
    //alert (id);
if (id == 'close')
{
    $(".aa").fadeOut("slow");
}
else if (id == '1' || id == '2' || id == '3' )
{    $(".aa").filter('#'+id+"div").fadeToggle("slow").end().not('#'+id+"div").fadeOut("slow").end();     //2 ends for not and filter destructive methods.   
}

else
{
    //$(".aa").click(function(){ return false; });//this statement is the problem

    $(".aa").fadeOut("slow");    
}
});
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".aa").click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

also here:

http://jsfiddle.net/p6c93/

Comment: Hi Matthew, but works the same way as my "return false;" statement, without the  $(".aa").fadeOut("slow"); statement, the window can't be closed if the users click outside of the window.

Comment: it works a little better than my original "return false" statement in that it allows clicking on the "close" to close the window.

Comment: sorry maybe I don't understand what you are trying to have happen could you clarify

Comment: I want the window to close when users click on "close" or any where outside the window (except on the buttons).

Comment: ok I get it. Basically you should do it differently. Js fiddle is down now so i cant show you that way...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I just use the bubbling up nature of JS. The bubbling up nature of javascript is confusing in jquery because a click event bubbles up instead of stopping at the clicked element. Anyway, the code in the last "else" block is quite simple once I understood this fact about JS

```
else 
{
    if (event.target.className == "aa")
        return;//or event.preventDefault()
    else
        $(".aa").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so jsfiddle keeps going down so I will try to explain to you what you should do:

change your "pop up" divs so that the are the child of a wrapper div. This wrapper div should have css something like this:

```
.wrapper {
   z-index: 1000;
   opacity: 1.0;
   position:absolute;
   left :0px;
   top: 0px;
   display: none;
   height: 100%;
   widthL 100%;
}
```

(basically it is a completely invisible and takes up the whole screen). Then give the aa class a higher `z-index` like 10001.

If you do this it will clear everything up for you. You won't have to capture clicks on the document and filter them anymore. You just capture clicks on either the x button or the wrapper div and hide the wrapper like this:

```
$(".wrapper").click(function(e) {
      $(this).toggle();
});
```

I hope this is enough to point you in the right direction...

(NOTE THIS IS ALL COMPLETELY UNTESTED)