# jQuery filter syntax troubleshooting

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble understanding why my simple jquery code does not get recognized. When a user clicks on a tab, the function supposes to toggle the tabs' classes.  I am using the filter and not methods to determine which tab was clicked.  The similar line of code works for me before, but it does not seem to work in my new code.  The function can capture the the id of the element just fine, but the filter parameter does not work.

Please give some insights on the statement that contains the filter method.  In my example code, if I click on tab 1, how do I get it to do something (ie add class)?  [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rq2KD/)

edit: Please give reasons why my `filter` statement does not work, I am using it in combination of `not` to filter in and out elements, which has worked for me before.  See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657911/jquery-troubleshooting-this-jquery-code)

TIA

```
    $(function(){

    $('.tabbar').click(function(event){ 
        var id = event.target.id;
          $('.tabbar').filter('#'+id).addClass("tabn");
          //alert(id);
    });
});
```

HTML code

```
    <div class="tabbar" > <span name="tabs" class="tabm" id="tab1"  >tab 1</span>
<span name="tabs" class="tabn" id="tab2"  >tab 2</span> 
      </div>
```

Comment: You are confusing ``filter`` with ``find``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.tabbar').click(function(event){
    // you can use $(this) to get the clicked element
    $(".tabbar span").removeClass("tabn"); // remove the class from other tabs
    $(this).addClass("tabn"); //and add to the current one
});
```

Comment: Thanks Radagaisus, from Paul's insight, I guess I should use ".tabbar span" before I call the filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.tabbar').filter('#'+id).addClass("tabn");
```

Searches for an element with class `.tabbar` and `id` id. You want to search within that class so you can use:

```
  $('.tabbar').find('#'+id).addClass("tabn");
```

And change addClass to toggleClass if you want it to toggle.

However, Since id's are unique, it's faster to just use:

```
  $('#'+id).addClass("tabn");
```

And since event.target refers to the DOM Element it's even faster to use

```
  $(event.target).addClass("tabn");
```

and never worry about the id.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the explanation in your first sentence.  That is why my code does not work.